# What's wrong with this while loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a function that filters through documents in mongoDB collection and returns all results that has a date that matches a Friday, Saturday or Sunday. This behaves as expected. However, now I need to match those results to determine if they fall on the weekend coming, however my while loop is only returning one result when it should return three. What is going wrong?

```
//FIND ALL ENTRIES THAT FALL ON A WEEKEND
function weekendPlans(callback) {
  Entry.aggregate(
      [
          { "$redact": {
              "$cond": {
                  "if": {
                      "$or": [
                          { "$eq": [ { "$dayOfWeek": "$selectedDate" }, 1 ] },
                          { "$eq": [ { "$dayOfWeek": "$selectedDate" }, 6 ] },
                          { "$eq": [ { "$dayOfWeek": "$selectedDate" }, 7 ] }
                      ]
                  },
                  "then": "$$KEEP",
                  "else": "$$PRUNE"
              }
          }}
      ],
      // GET THE RESULTS AND RETURN IF selectedDate MATCHES THIS WEEKEND
      function(err,results) {
        var i = results.length;
        var theWeekend;
        console.log(results)

        // EVERYTHING WORKS UNTIL HERE
        while(i--) {
          if(results[i].selectedDate === friday || saturday || sunday) {
              theWeekend = results[i];
              //console.log(theWeekend);
              break;
          }
        }
        callback(err, theWeekend)
      }
)};
```

Expected result:

```
[ { _id: 56fffb6ceb76276c8f39e3f4,
    url: 'http://wellnessmama.com/13700/benefits-coconut-oil-pets/',
    title: 'Benefits of Coconut Oil for Pets - Wellness Mama',
    selectedDate: Sat Apr 02 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST),
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56fffb8eeb76276c8f39e3f5,
    url: 'https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11404770',
    title: 'The Trouble with CloudFlare | Hacker News',
    selectedDate: Sun Apr 03 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST),
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 56fffb5ceb76276c8f39e3f3,
    url: 'http://londonist.com/2015/11/where-to-eat-and-drink-in-balham',
    title: 'Where To Eat And Drink In... Balham  | Londonist',
    selectedDate: Fri Apr 01 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST),
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Current result:

```
{ _id: 56fffb5ceb76276c8f39e3f3,
  url: 'http://londonist.com/2015/11/where-to-eat-and-drink-in-balham',
  title: 'Where To Eat And Drink In... Balham  | Londonist',
  selectedDate: Fri Apr 01 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST),
  __v: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
results[i].selectedDate === friday || saturday || sunday
```

to

```
~results[i].selectedDate.indexOf('Fri') || 
~results[i].selectedDate.indexOf('Sat') || 
~results[i].selectedDate.indexOf('Sun')
```

because you need to check every variable with a value and if the day string is in the date string.